# NVD3 dynamic domain [0, maxVisible]?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3[NVD3](http://nvd3.org/index.html) to show a `lineChart`. The legend is very useful, and I want to enable the ability to only display a line for a single legend element, however the default configuration will transition the yAxis to be `[min,max]` of that legend element. I would like it to always display `[0,max]`. I found I can do this, however it will have a domain of 0 to max of all legend elements, not 0 to visible legened elements. Does anyone know if it is possible?

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d['values'], function(d2) {
    return d2['open'];
  });
});

chart.yDomain([0, yMax]);
```

**UPDATE:** I was able to achieve what I wanted with the following:

```
chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) {
  var i = -1;
  var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    i++;
    if(e.disabled[i] == false){
      return d3.max(d['values'], function(d2) {
        return(d2['open']);
      });
    }
  });
  chart.yDomain([0, yMax]);
});
```

Comment: Disabling a data series by clicking on the legend will set a property `disabled: true` on the corresponding series' object. You could filter for that when calculating the maximum values of all visible series. If you could share a working demo, I would happy to post an answer implementing this.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was getting as well. How do you access the different legend objects? I did see there was a `chart.legend` function, but based on inspecting it and reading the docs, it was not apparent how to access the enabled/disabled attribute.